# Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(String?!)'

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to add usernames from Parse in an array to display them in a UITableView, but get an error when I'm appending the usernames to my array.

The error I get is: Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(String?!)'

What am I doing wrong?

```
var usernames = [""]

func updateUsers() {      
    var query = PFUser.query()
    query!.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
    var fetchedUsers = query!.findObjects()

    for fetchedUser in fetchedUsers! {
        self.usernames.append(fetchedUser.username)
    }
}
```

Comment: How about declaring the array like this: `var usernames:[String] = []`

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem. I declare the array as an empty array and for unwrap the optional with the following code:

```
var usernames = [String]()

self.usernames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

    for fetchedUser in fetchedUsers! {
        if let username = fetchedUser.username as String! {
            self.usernames.append(username)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`PFUser.username` is an optional, and you can't append an optional into a `String` array in Swift. This is because the optional can be `nil`, and a String array in Swift only accepts strings.

You need to either force unwrap the optional, or use if-let syntax to add it if it exists.

Force Unwrap

```
self.usernames.append(fetchedUser.username! as String)
```

Or if-let

```
if let name = fetchedUser.username as? String {
  self.usernames.append(name)
}
```

Plus as NRKirby mentions in the comments on your question, you might want to look at initialising the `usernames` array differently. At the moment the first element is an empty string.