# Swift: Can't get rid of "Optional" when setting cell text label

Tags: swift, option-type

I've spent a fair bit of time trying to solve this but I'm having no joy.

I have an array (levelArrayName) created in my appDelegate, which is populated by a sqlite database:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var database:COpaquePointer = nil
var levelArray: [[Int]] = []
var levelArrayName: [[String]] = []

func checkdatabase(){
    //check is database exist at path.....
    var dirPaths:NSString

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! NSString;

    let databasePath = dirPaths.stringByAppendingString("/rugby.sqlite")
    let dbpath = databasePath.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let filemanager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    if (!filemanager.fileExistsAtPath(databasePath))
    {
        let fileForCopy = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("rugby",ofType:"sqlite")
        filemanager.copyItemAtPath(fileForCopy!, toPath:databasePath, error: nil)
    }

    let error = sqlite3_open(dbpath!, &database)
    if error != SQLITE_OK
    {
        println("error while opening");
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }

}


func getLevels() {
    var selectQuery="SELECT * FROM level"
    var stmt:COpaquePointer = nil
    var result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, selectQuery, -1, &stmt, nil);

    if result != SQLITE_OK
    {
        println("failed  \(sqlite3_errmsg(database))")
        println("failed  \(sqlite3_errcode(database))")
    }
    else
    {
        result = sqlite3_step(stmt)

        while result == SQLITE_ROW {

            var levelID = Int(sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0))
            var attackID = Int(sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 2))
            var defenceID = Int(sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 2))
            var runs = Int(sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 3))
            var tries = Int(sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 4))
            var name_buf = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 5)
            var name = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(name_buf))

            result = sqlite3_step(stmt)

            self.levelArray += [[levelID, attackID, defenceID, runs, tries]]
            self.levelArrayName += [["\(name)"]]
        }
    }

}
```

I then use this array in one of my tableviewcontrollers to set the cell label:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

class LevelsViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate,     UITableViewDataSource {


var levelArrayName = appDelegate.levelArrayName

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return appDelegate.levelArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LevelCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = levelArrayName[indexPath.row][0]

    return cell

    //return UITableViewCell()


}
```

However, the cell label shows "Optional:" before the string from the array.

I've tried unwrapping the appDelegate.levelArrayName, but I can't seem to get this to work.

I'm sure I'm missing something easy, but would appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else who had the same issue as me, I managed to work out the answer, helped greatly by this thread: [Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(String?!)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756722/cannot-invoke-append-with-an-argument-list-of-type-string/29760175#29760175)

In AppDelegate I changed my code:

```
self.levelArrayName += [["\(name)"]]
```

To

```
if let nameArray = name as String! {self.levelArrayName.append(name!)}
```

And then no need to unwrap in tableviewcontroller, so this code worked:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = levelArrayName[indexPath.row]
```

This may seem a easy answer, but I hope this helps others

Answer (score 5):

You need to unwrap the element at the index in the array

```
if let text = levelArrayName[indexPath.row][0] {
    cell.textLabel?.text = text
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however this gives me the error: "Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type" on the line  - if let text = levelArrayName[indexPath.row][0] {