# Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(Range<String.Index>)'

Tags: swift, string, substring, interleave

The error I’m seeing is the title: `Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(Range<String.Index>)'`

While practicing string interleaving in Swift, I'm trying to append the substring of one string to another. [This other question covers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180346/append-string-in-swift) appending one string to another, which is not my question. [And this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756722/cannot-invoke-append-with-an-argument-list-of-type-string) is an entirely different error thrown. [The Swift documentation on Strings and Characters](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html) **does not seem to cover appending a substring to a String.**

This line (and the similar one) throws an error.

```
result.append(str2.index(after: str2Index)..<str2.endIndex)
```

How do I resolve this and append the substring to the string?

```
var str1 = "abcde"
var str2 = "fgh"
print(str1) // prints 'abcde'
print(str2) // prints 'fgd'

var str1Index = str1.startIndex
var str2Index = str2.startIndex
var result = String()
var resultIndex = result.startIndex

while str1Index != str1.endIndex && str2Index != str2.endIndex {
    result.insert(str1[str1Index],at: resultIndex)
    str1Index = str1.index(after: str1Index)
    resultIndex = result.index(after: resultIndex)

    result.insert(str2[str2Index], at: resultIndex)
    resultIndex = result.index(after: resultIndex)
    str2Index = str2.index(after: str2Index)
}

if str1Index != str1.endIndex {
    // This does not work, throws above mentioned error 
    result.append(str2.index(after: str2Index)..<str2.endIndex)
} else if str2Index != str2.endIndex {
    // This does not work, throws above mentioned error
    result.append(str1.index(after: str1Index)..<str1.endIndex)
}

print(result) // should print 'afbgchde'
```

PS, corrections or comments on my algorithm are also appreciated :)

Comment: Do you need to convert Range to NSRange?

Comment: What is the error that you're seeing?

Comment: @Caleb the error I am seeing is the title of the question

Comment: @NonCreature0714 That reads like a question title; you should clarify your question to clearly include the error text. If I was fooled, others will be too.

Comment: @onnoweb is that a suggestion or a question?

Comment: Why downvote? I’m responsive to comments, and many good questions on SO use the error message as a question title

Comment: Please read the error message. `result` is `String` and `index(after` returns `Range<String.Index>`. It's a type mismatch.

Comment: @vadian thanks, I know it’s a type mismatch, and I appreciate the comment. I choose not to list the various casts I tried in lieu of brevity

Answer (score 2):

You can use zip to pair the characters, join them into a string using reduce(into:) method and add the remaining characters from the longest string:

```
let str1 = "abcde"
let str2 = "fgh"
print(str1) // prints 'abcde'
print(str2) // prints 'fgh'
let str1Count = str1.count
let str2Count = str2.count
let result = zip(str1,str2).reduce(into: "") {  
    $0.append($1.0)
    $0.append($1.1)
} + ( str1Count > str2Count ?
    str1.suffix(str1Count-str2Count) :
    str2.suffix(str2Count-str1Count) )

print(result) // 'afbgchde'
```

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because `append()` takes a single collection element as
argument (here: a single `Character`), and not an index range.

You can use `+=` (or `append(contentsOf:)`) and a subscript with a one-sided range to append the “remainders” of both
strings to the result:

```
result += str1[str1Index...]
result += str2[str2Index...]
```

Testing `str1Index != str1.endIndex` is not necessary, the range is empty
in that case.

The while-loop can also be simplified: The `resultIndex` is not needed
if you *append* to the `result` String:

```
var str1Index = str1.startIndex
var str2Index = str2.startIndex
var result = String()

while str1Index != str1.endIndex && str2Index != str2.endIndex {
    result.append(str1[str1Index])
    str1.formIndex(after: &str1Index)
    result.append(str2[str2Index])
    str2.formIndex(after: &str2Index)
}

result += str1[str1Index...]
result += str2[str2Index...]
```